# Inserting live data in MongoDB using ASP.Net Core 2.0 C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new in MongoDB and trying to insert live data that I get from a lot of sensors in MongoDB. As I am dealing with large amount of data I tried 2 different approaches to insert data in database. First I did it one by one, when I got data I inserted that in database. 
The second approach is I collect data and use a timer to insertMany data every 1 second. 
First approach was too slow but the second one was better and faster with lower count of connections to DB. 
This is part of the code that I developed :

```
_timer.Stop();
            System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(_lockObject);
            try
            {
                Task t1 = Task.FromResult(0);
                Task t2 = Task.FromResult(0);
                Task t3 = Task.FromResult(0);

                if (Data1.Count > 0)
                {
                    t1 = Collection1.InsertManyAsync(Data1);
                }
                if (Data2.Count > 0)
                {
                    t2 = Collection2.InsertManyAsync(Data2);
                }
                if (Data3.Count > 0)
                {
                    t3 = Collection3.InsertManyAsync(Data3);
                }               

                Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                Data1.Clear();
                Data2.Clear();
                Data3.Clear();
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
                _timer.Start();
            }
```

my question is, if I want to collect request and insert them as a list with 1000 items, how can I do that without losing live data. I know that I need to lock my list while inserting in database but in that time I will lose live data because my list is locked?

Comment: Running something with "as much data is collected within one second" sounds like more of a hack. Ideally set an upper limit for a "number of items collected" and then do the `InsertMany` when that "buffer" reaches that point instead. The only real limitation on how much data can be sent through the API call is that the "driver" will actually attempt to break down to indvidual requests under 16MB chunks if necessary. But you most likely don't want to accumulate 100's of MB of data or GB of data before sending a request. A couple of thousand or whatever fits under 16MB is usually most optimal.

Comment: The main problem in the question is a general "which is best" is too broad. We can point out things like it's better to control the batch insertions by "limits" rather than "time", but those are "broad strokes" in themselves. Note also that these are just single requests. So this code itself has a maximum of three "in flight" operations ( therefore connections ) at the same time. And that's not really a lot.

Comment: Thank you. Because we will increase the sensors, I do not want to lose any part of data. But that was a really good advice for limiting data by count instead of time. This is a better approach.

Comment: I think now my question shows the problem better.

Comment: Looks like you need a thread-safe FIFO queue, not a list. Why do you lose data if you lock the list anyway?

Comment: @CodeCaster Because I put live data in a list to use `insertMany` instead of `insertOne` to database. I need to lock my list to prevent inserting new items in list and insert the whole list in MongoDB.I dont want to usert `insertOne` because it is too slow.